# Visual Studio 2019 swapping lines when debugging - hit break point

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I have a strange issue - when I debug my code in visual studio 2019. It almost appears as if my last edited line of code, or where my cursor was last gets swapped with the line below it as soon as a break point is hit:

Example:

the code would be

```
foreach(int i in ints[])
{
  int a = i; //break point here
}
```

when hitting the break point. I get an error that my code has changed and I cannot continue over my break point because of an error, this is frustrating because sometimes only an undo can find what was changed.

Once the issue is found, the code now looks like this:

```
{ 
foreach(int i in ints[])

  int a = i; //break point here
}
```

the curly brace has been swapped with the foreach

Comment: There is currently a bug in VS that displays that message erroneously: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/705494/without-any-changes-to-source-files-edits-were-mad.html

Comment: VS2019 version 16.3 had a hard release deadline.  It shows, they were not done and it is going to take quite a while for them to recover.  Best way ahead is to reinstall 16.2.5 and ignore update notifications.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#installing-an-earlier-release